# Execute some regexps after branch cycle finishes

Tags: sed

I have a file with dates that separated with tabs and newlines:

```
20171113T090319Z    20171120T125820Z    20171214T082222Z
20171213T074023Z    20171229T070931Z    20171115T112126Z
20171212T075236Z    20171212T121328Z    20171024T084925Z
20171024T171827Z    20171115T120126Z    20171218T093732Z
20171027T065928Z    20171212T133230Z    20171212T085634Z
20171219T162619Z    20171109T142727Z    20171114T145032Z
```

I need to transform this file in such way. Make it single line and append some text in front of each date:

```
imageTag=20171113T090319Z imageTag=20171120T125820Z imageTag=20171214T082222Z imageTag=20171218T125131Z imageTag=20171017T141829Z imageTag=20171127T160931Z
```

I'm new to `sed` and other tools and that is why I want to say sorry for ugly code

first approach just use separate `sed` commands for transformation:

```
 cat test.txt |
 sed 's/\t/\n/g' |
 sed 's/^/imageTag=/g' |
 sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

Then I decided to rewrite it in a single sed:

```
cat test.txt | sed -e ':x;N;s/[\t\n]/ imageTag=/g;bx; s/^/imageTag=/'
```

But in this example last part `s/^/imageTag=/` is never executed.

**So my question: How execute code after `bx;`(branch unconditionally)**

I rewrited it in such way `cat test.txt | sed -e ':x;N;s/[\t\n]/ imageTag=/g;/^imageTag/! s/^/imageTag=/;bx;'`. But it is just work around.

Comment: any particular reason to have it in single sed script other than learning purpose? replacing your first sed with tr and final sed with paste, you'd get a simple to read and maintain code `<ip.txt tr '\t' '\n' | sed 's/^/imageTag=/' | paste -sd' '`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/\t/\n/;s/^/imageTag=/Mg;1h;1!H;$!d;x;y/\n/ /' file
```

Translate each tab to a newline. Insert the required string at the front of each line (the `M` flag in the substitute command invokes the multi-line mode which allows the use of the `^` and `$` in a regexp to represent the start/end of line); Gather up each line into the hold space and at the end of the file translate each newline to a space.

Answer (score 1):

Your script looks uncannily complicated.  If your `sed` recognizes `\t` for tab and `\n` for newline, try

```
sed 's/\(^\|\t\|\n\)/ imageTag=/g;s/^ //;s/ imageTag=$//' test.txt
```

The two final commands are simple fixups to handle beginning and end of line.  I'm sure they could be avoided in the first place but this seems straightforward enough.

Notice also how we avoid the unsightly [useless use of `cat`.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

As witnessed in comments, this isn't terribly portable, though; perhaps prefer a more well-defined tool.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(^|\t|\n)/ imageTag=/g;s/^ //;s/ imageTag=$//' test.txt
```

The `-0777` "slurp mode" will read the entire file into memory, so maybe don't do this if the input is multiple gigabytes.

Ironically, `sed` is standardized by POSIX, while Perl has no official specification; but because there is only one implementation of Perl, and POSIX failed to specify many things in `sed` exactly, the *de facto* end result is that Perl is more portable than `sed`.

Comment: `\n` is never going to match in your code as sed strips them before processing and adds them while printing.. the capture group is not needed too.. and OP wants output in single line..

Comment: @Sundeep That is not universally true; I tested this on a Debian box before posting the answer. The actual sample in the question is not tab-delimited so I had to adjust it, though. The grouping is required, though obviously not for capturing anything.

Comment: oh, that is strange indeed.. in that case, wouldn't it add `imageTag=` at end of line and another at start of next line? I checked on GNU sed (after converting to tab separated input) and your code would only add `imageTag=` to each date and output won't be in single line

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for your answer. but as I know your example process input file line by line and result will contain same number of line. And I need in one line

Comment: It replaces the newlines with other text so the result is indeed a single line.

Comment: I didn't get a trailing `imageTag=` in my test but I see how that could happen on some platforms. I updated the answer to fix this up, too.

Comment: There is a comma instead of a semicolon in front of the last `s` command, and FWIW, it doesn't end up as a single line for me either, for both GNU sed (prepends `imageTag=` everywhere) and macOS sed (doesn't do anything at all).

Comment: @BenjaminW Thanks, fixed the comma. I'll need to check what version of `sed` I had on the machine I used.